# How much is the relevance of a synthetic benchmark?

Tags: publications, research-process, computer-science, experiment-design

Often researchers verify their proposed algorithm or techniques using standard benchmarks. My question is related to performance of a benchmark application.

If a researcher propose a new performance optimization or analysis technique optimizing based on a *particular factor*, is it **enough** to only use a *synthetic benchmark* for verification. If instead a standard benchmark application is used its performance may be subjected to multiple factors. It will be difficult to argue that improvement is only due to the *particular factor*, the researcher optimized for.

Let me give an example. Often a synthetic benchmark is used in synchronization lock related research. Psuedocode of benchmark:

In every thread

```
For N times // where N is in millions
       //do something in the non-critical section part
       acquire a lock
          // do something in the critical section
       release a lock
```

Such a benchmark has been used in some notable paper's of the field. But now most of the research use some applications that uses the lock.

The problem is, it is difficult to individually identify and quantify each factor that affect a benchmark lock-sensitive application performance. Despite the application being lock-sensitive there are a host of other factor that affect the application performance. It would be easier to do for a synthetic benchmark, where a researcher can limit the code.

How convincing an argument in a research paper is if it is solely based on analysis on synthetic benchmarks?

Comment: Why not run experiments on both?

Comment: It is easier to explain results as synthetic benchmark is focused on *particular factor*. Extracting contribution of the *particular factor* in the benchmark application run is difficult. So it will be difficult to justify results.

Comment: @ajit Ease of explaining results is an argument for using a synthetic benchmark in the first place, but not an argument in favor of not using realistic benchmarks. A realistic benchmark supports conclusions about the real-world applicability of your work, which is an important quality of research.

Answer (score 2):

Having just a synthetic benchmark is generally weaker than having a realistic benchmark, but better than nothing.

There some more considerations to be taken into account.

First, quality considerations: Is the design rationale of the benchmark clearly communicated? Was there any effort made to reflect realistic cases? Was the benchmark designed with input from multiple, independent experts (ideally different authors than the author of the paper, due to researcher bias)? Have independent experts been consulted to validate the benchmark? Is the benchmark publicly available and well-documented?

Second, historical considerations: Has the benchmark recently been used in other research? The more widely a benchmark is used, the better, since it will allow an easy comparison between different works.

Comment: Who can be considered as the **independent** expert?

Comment: @ajit First of all, it's better if the benchmark was developed by other persons than the author of the paper. Then, it's good if the benchmark is developed by a group of people who don't usually work together (like a PI and his PhD students etc.).

Comment: Synthetic benchmark are often simple, like in the question. You don't require much of an expertise to  develop them. Will it suffice to cite some old(few decade) seminal papers where it was used? Or given it simplicity it would not be prudent to cite, just use them.

Comment: @ajit If it's an established benchmark in the field, that is a good thing. But since it's decades old, it's possible that the field has produced some improved methods for benchmarking. So, it would be your job to read up the current literature in the field and understand their benchmarking standards.